# Gmail markup for online event

Tags: gmail, schema.org, markup

While there is good documentation around sending markup emails for specifying offline event. [Refrence](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation) Can someone help me out on how to add handle an online event?
The issue with offline event is that I need to enter a proper postal address, however in our case the location is simply a url.
Things I have already tried

- Putting type of location as `VirtualLocation`, but that gives error
- Entering empty strings in `PostalAddress` fields
- Marking `eventAttendanceMode` as `https://schema.org/OnlineEventAttendanceMode`, it gives error

Does gmail support markups for online events? Common sense says it should.

Comment: reading through doc serchengine and mail for 30+min  . conculosion not supported on mail. no this type def in mails.

Comment: read their blogs : https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/03/new-properties-virtual-or-canceled-events

Comment: @KayesFahim This works for search events, but it was not working for emails.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @kayes-fahim comment you can find more information on their [blog](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/03/new-properties-virtual-or-canceled-events), and [documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/event#virtual-location).

By the blog post you could use the `virtualLocation` but you also need to set the `eventAttendanceMode` to `OnlineEventAttendanceMode`. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/03/new-properties-virtual-or-canceled-events#mark-events-as-online-only)

Comment: have u try on https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/

Comment: While this might work for SEO optimized events, but this is not working for emails.  @TaiwaneseDavidCheng is also right...I also tried copy pasting this thing on email markup tester, it throws error `VirtualLocation is not a valid target type for the location property.`

Comment: Maybe the tool doesn't support it yet, there is a note in documentation"You can start using the VirtualLocation type even though it's still pending on schema.org.". There is a complete example in <https://schema.org/eventAttendanceMode> and <https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/event>.